# laravel 5.5 handle request with nested object

Tags: javascript, php, json, httprequest, laravel-5.5

I'm currently working on a Laravel 5.5 project and I'm having a strange behavior with a particular json request.

My json :

```
{
    first_name:"MYFIRSTNAME",
    last_name:"MYLASTNAME",
    location:{
        data: {
            address:"3 something street",
            postal_code:"42000",
            lng_lat:"-1.8263223,43.2150621"
        }
    },
    profile_picture:"http://linktoprofilepic.jpg",
    stats:{ 
        data: {
            stat1:335,
            stat2:312, 
            stat3:32
        }
    },
    verification_text:"#trend"
}
```

So I am sending the above JSON as a PUT request to my controller, without any validation rules at the moment. When debugging in my controller with Laravel s debugging function **dd( $request->all() )** , I get the following :

```
array:5 [
  "first_name" => "MYFIRSTNAME"
  "last_name" => "MYLASTNAME"
  "profile_picture" => "http:linktoprofilepic.jpg"
  "" => array:1 [
    "data" => array:3 [
      "stat1" => 335
      "stat2" => 312
      "stat3" => 32
    ]
  ]
  "verification_text" => "#trend"
]
```

As you can see the nested object **location** is not present and the nested object **stats** now has a empty string as a property name. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or is it that Laravel does not support nested objects ? Please someone enlighten me on this issue. Thx

Comment: I doubt Laravel is mangling the data it received.  So, how are you sending it and how are you constructing the object?  Did you check your browser developer tools to monitor the http request and make sure the data you send is what you've posted above?

Comment: screenshot of data being sent : [link](https://imgur.com/XKjxeQj)
screenshot of response with debug : [link](https://i.imgur.com/xchyX05.jpg)
I am using axios to make the request on a Vuejs2 project

Comment: Does `dd($request->json()->all());` work?

Comment: No i get the same result.. and i've just noticed that the property documents is missing as well

Comment: Also if this might help understand, when i try nesting my json inside data property like so : { data : json } i get this as response : 
[link](https://paste.ofcode.org/37fp2eLKgMCwZbcbNtPP8hQ)
The data property name becomes empty string

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out the problem, **@James** thx for your concern ! It was something you said that helped me find the issue. You said "I doubt Laravel is mangling the data it received." and you were right. I'm actually using a middleware that transforms the request data property names, and this middleware was set in the routes, therefore I completely missed it and forgot about it. It s a bit embarrassing ^^ Thanks for your help !